# Why am I getting discoloured text in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

This is a snip of my chrome window: [image: A snip of the chrome window]

This is a snip of notepad text which is perfect:

[image]

You see, the text has got discolored. But look at the address bar, there the text is in black. Please tell me the possible reason and solution. Following is the config of my system:

- 2 GB RAM
- 2.70 GHz
- 320 GB Hard Disk
- 256 MB Graphics Card

Comment: Please perform the windows color calibration first.

Comment: @Satoh I have it done already and no other program except chrome is showing this type of text

Comment: Have you tried resetting Chrome to its default settings?

Comment: Have you messed with ClearType settings? Even if you haven't, try selecting what looks best to you from `Control Panel / Appearance and Personalization / ClearType tuner` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the hardware acceleration. Type chrome://flags in your chrome and disable the hardware-acceleration and relaunch the web brower. Boom, it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after a restart!! I don't know how :D.